# how to retrieve a @variable from sql(enterprise manager) in vb?

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql, vb.net

my sql statement adds details of a new employee returns a `@employeeID`. I need to retrieve this `@employeeID` to display the details of the `newly added employee` in my `viewprofile.asp.vb`. How do i go about coding the VB to retrieve the `@employeeID` from the SQL and include the @employeeID variable in my VB code so that it displays my newly added information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use add a SqlParameter with Direction **Output**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306574

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server Query:

```
Select @employeeID = Ident_Current('employee table')
```

In codebehind:

```
employeeID = SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>

```
<html>
  <head><title>Using Stored Procedures With Output Parameters</title></head>
  <body>
    <form runat="server" method="post">
      Enter a State Code:
      <asp:Textbox id="txtRegion" runat="server" />
      <asp:Button id="btnSubmit" runat="server"
                  Text="Search" OnClick="Submit" />
      <br/><br/>
      <asp:label id="lblRecords" runat="server" />
      <br/><br/>
      <asp:DataGrid id="dgOutput" runat="server" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

<script language="VB" runat="server">
Sub Submit(Source As Object, E As EventArgs)

  Dim strConnection As String = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("NWind")
  Dim objConnection As New SqlConnection(strConnection)
  Dim objCommand As New SqlCommand("sp_CustomersByStateWithCount",objConnection)
  objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

  Dim objParameter As New SqlParameter("@region", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15)
  objCommand.Parameters.Add(objParameter)
  objParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
  objParameter.Value = txtRegion.text

  Dim objOutputParameter As New SqlParameter("@matches", SqlDbType.Int)
  objCommand.Parameters.Add(objOutputParameter)
  objOutputParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

  objConnection.Open()

  Dim objDataReader As SqlDataReader
  objDataReader = objCommand.ExecuteReader()

  dgOutput.DataSource = objDataReader
  dgOutput.DataBind()

  objCommand.Connection.Close()
  objCommand.Connection.Open()
  objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
  lblRecords.Text = "Matches: " & CInt(objCommand.Parameters(1).Value)

  objConnection.close()
End Sub
</script>


---------------------------------------------------
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim cn As SqlConnection
        Dim sql As String
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand

        cn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=PEREGRINE;" & _
                               "Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI")
        cn.Open()
        sql = "CREATE PROCEDURE sp_CustomersByStateWithCount @region nvarchar(15), @matches int OUTPUT AS " & _
              "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM Customers WHERE region = @region ORDER BY CompanyName " & _
              "SET @matches = @@rowcount"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, cn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Console.WriteLine("Procedure created!")
    End Sub
End Module
```